# Trying to understand SKLearn regression predictions array

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm very new to Python programming, and even newer to SKLearn and ML.
So please forgive my ignorance on these subjects.

I've started to experiment with SKLearn regression models and code, but hit a fundamental problem understanding the results of this experimental code.

Given the code below, I'm trying to figure out what the result of the LinearRegression model predict() function is, in relation to the hypothetical daily sales figures of an item, stored in the sales_data array.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

sales_data = [3, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8, 5, 10, 9, 6, 4, 7, 11, 6, 3, 1, 4, 5, 8, 10, 7] # May be a much larger array in int's

x_train = []
y_train = []
x_test = []
y_test = []
X = sales_data
Y = sales_data

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.25, train_size = 0.75, random_state = 1)

x_train = np.array(x_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
x_test = np.array(x_test)
y_test = np.array(y_test)

x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 1)

lregressor = LinearRegression()
lregressor.fit(x_train, y_train)
lregressor_pred = lregressor.predict(x_test) # Trying to understand what the predicted array represents to sales_data
```

1) Does the predicted array represent possible outcomes for the next days sales of the item ?

2) Is the predicted array ordered from the most likely to the least likely sales figure ?

If neither of the above is true, please could you explain in simple terms what the predicted array does represent, and how it could be used to forcast the next days item sales, or guess the next integer that might be added to the sales_data array.

I've also used similar code with LogisticRegression and RandomForest regression models, but still don't understand the prediction results, and how to use them.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Does the predicted array represent possible outcomes for the next days sales of the item ?

No. It's an array of predictions for each sample in `x_test`.

> 2) Is the predicted array ordered from the most likely to the least likely sales figure ?

No. It's ordered in the same order that `x_test` is ordered in.

Comment: Could you expand or explain more on "No. It's an array of predictions for each sample in x_test" and "No. It's ordered in the same order that x_test is ordered in", as I'm a complete novice with this stuff.

Comment: If you're a complete novice, this may be a bit hard - I recommend reading "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow"

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out the answer to my own question, but I'm still not sure I've got it right.
But I'm sure the eagle eye readers will comment on the errors of my way, which would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

sales_data = [3, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8, 5, 10, 9, 6, 4, 7, 11, 6, 3, 1, 4, 5, 8, 10, 7] # May be a much larger array in int's

X = list(range(0, len(sales_data)))
Y = sales_data

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.25, train_size = 0.75, random_state = 1)

x_train = np.array(x_train).reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
x_test = np.array(x_test).reshape(-1, 1)
y_test = np.array(y_test)

x_day = len(sales_data) + 1
x_prediction = np.array([x_day]).reshape(-1, 1)

lregressor = LinearRegression().fit(x_train, y_train)
lregressor_pred = lregressor.predict(x_prediction)
lregressor_pred_list = list(np.rint(lregressor_pred)) # The returned list contains a prediction of next day's sales
```